# Loading known files by variable in webpack using require

Tags: webpack

I currently try to switch over to webpack.
I have a project structure that looks similar to this:

```
node_modules
    @my-namespace/moduleA
    @my-namespace/moduleB
    @my-namespace/moduleC
    ...
```

In each of the modules I might have the following directories

```
ui/controllers
        main.js
        edit.js
```

My html structure will have the information about the current *module*  and the *controller* that should be loaded in this form:

```html
<html data-module="moduleA" data-controller="edit">
```

In my main entry point I have something like that.

```js
const $ = require('jquery')
const moduleName = $('html').data().module
const controllerName = $('html').data().controller

const controller = require('/ui/controllers/' + moduleName + '/' + controllerName)
```

How can I *preload* all of my controllers (I know all modules where I want to search for) so that `require('/ui/controllers/' + moduleName + '/' + controllerName)` will find them.

I think I can accomplish this writing an own plugin and I already took a look into `ContextReplacementPlugin` and it seems that using `result.resolveDependencies` in combination `ContextElementDependency` might be the solution. But the documentation does not have much information about that.

I'm currently stuck with the part in

```js
cmf.plugin('before-resolve', function(result, callback) {
   if (result.request == 'ui/controller') {
    // what do I need to do here so that 'after-resolve' is reached   

    return callback(null, result)
   } else {
     callback()
   }
})
```

So that I can add all dependencies in the:

```js
cmf.plugin('after-resolve', function(result, callback) {
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently solved it with a pre processing step. I search for all file in the different modules that I want to combine with web pack, copy them to a temporary build directory, and then compose a loader base on the found controllers that has is structured like that:

**constroler-loader.js**

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')

exports.get = function(controllerName, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (controllerName === 'moduleA/controllerA') {
      require.ensure(['./moduleA/controllerA'], function(require) {
        try {
          const controller = require('./moduleA/controllerA');
          resolve(controller(options));
        } catch (e) {
          reject(new Error('controller "' + controllerName + '" could not be created.'))
        }
      });
    } else if (controllerName === 'moduleA/controllerB') {
      require.ensure(['./moduleA/controllerB'], function(require) {
        try {
          const controller = require('./controllers/events/overview');
          resolve(controller(options));
        } catch (e) {
          reject(new Error('controller "' + controllerName + '" could not be created.'))
        }
      });
    } else {
      reject(new Error('controller "' + controllerName + '" not found.'));
    }
  })
}
```

After that I run webpack on the build directory.