# Loading scripts using variables and ensure, but keep them in different chunks

Tags: webpack

I have a followup question to a previous on I already asked ([Loading known files by variable in webpack using require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328268)

In my web application I load different controllers depending on which site I am currently on. And I have some common scripts that are always loaded. The controller that should be loaded is stored in a `data-` attribute in the `html` tag.

The file structure is like this:

```
main.js
controllers/controllerA.js
controllers/controllerB.js
controllers/subpath/controllerC.js
```

If I use:

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
  const controller = require('./controllers/'+config.controller);
  controller()
});
```

Then all controllers are stored in one output file, but I would like to keep them in different chunks.

As mentioned in my other question I currently solve this this using a preprocessing step looking for all controllers and create an explicit `ensure` for each of them and use an `if` clause to decide which one should be loaded.

```
if( config.controller === 'controllerA' ) {
  require.ensure(['./controllers/controllerA'], function(require) {
    const controller = require('./controllers/controllerA');
    controller()
  });
}
```

This works fine, but seems to be wrong, is there a way how I can achieve that with on single `ensure` using variables?

**EDIT**

I found the issue [Dynamic require with code-split per file](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/441#issuecomment-53854368) but using:

```
require('bundle-loader!./controllers/'+config.controller)
```

Results into this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: callbacks[i] is not a function(…)

And seems to happen in the part generated by the bundle loader:

```
var cbs = [], 
data;
module.exports = function(cb) {
  if(cbs) cbs.push(cb);
  else cb(data);
}
require.ensure([], function(require) {
  data = require("!!./controllerA.js");
  var callbacks = cbs;
  cbs = null;
  for(var i = 0, l = callbacks.length; i < l; i++) {
    callbacks[i](data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With webpack 2.x and [Code Splitting with ES2015](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#code-splitting-with-es2015) the problem is now finally solved.

Instead of using `require.ensure` the `import` can be used and the code can be written this way:

```
function getController(controller) {
  return import(`./controllers/${controller}`)
    .then(controller => controller());
}

getController('controllerA')
.then(()=> {
  console.log('ok');
})
```

The controllers are now stored in individual files and loaded on-demand.